# Frame freezes even if started in a other Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, freeze

I want a Frame to be displayed while my Program connects with other Players. But even if the Frame is running in his own Thread it is still freezing while the Serversocket is trying to connect. How can I prevent it from freezing?

```
public static boolean connectH(String check, String data, int k){
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    message = "waiting for someone to connect to your " + check + "-game";
    th = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            c = new Canceler(message);
        }
    };
    th.start();
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(data));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not listen on port: " + data);
        Main.m.finishgame(-1);
    }


    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (in.readLine().equals(check)){
            out.println(k);
            c.remove();
            return true;
        }else{
            out.println(String.valueOf(-1));
            c.remove();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    c.remove();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How are you handling your threading? You might need to use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) in this situation.

Comment: `clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();` is causing your `JFrame` to freeze, since it's blocking the `Event Dispatcher Thread`. This part should be on another `Thread` or on `SwingWorker` as already stated :-)

Comment: You should not "run frames on separate threads".  All frames and GUI code should run on a single thread: the AWT-Dispatch thread.  You should move all other long-running code (such as waiting to accept a socket connection) to worker threads.  SwingWorker can make this easier.

Comment: But I want my other Windows to be frozen while the connection is built up. The only Window that is intended to react is the one that is newly opened in 
 th = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            c = new Canceler(message);
        }
    };
    th.start();

Comment: @125_m_125 You should never intentionally freeze the GUI, as it will appear to the user as if your application has crashed or hung (a bug), and you will not be able to respond to user input (e.g. mouse clicks) while the application is frozen. If you want to prevent the user from interacting with the GUI while something is happening (waiting for a connection, for example), then disable all the buttons in the GUI using setEnabled(false), and ignore GUI events like windowClosing, until the background activity has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example Applet will get you started.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Example extends JApplet
{
    private JButton _jButtonStartGameServer;
    private boolean _isStarted = false;
    private GameServer _gameServer = null;
    private JTextArea _jTextArea;
    private Thread _gameServerThread = null;
    private boolean _initialized = false;

    public Example()
    {
        System.out.println("ctor...");
    }

    private void initComponents()
    {
        if (_initialized)
        {
            return;
        }

        _jButtonStartGameServer = new JButton("Start Game Server");
        _jButtonStartGameServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if (!_isStarted)
                {
                    startupGameServer();
                }
                else
                {
                    shutdownGameServer();
                }
            }
        });
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        _jTextArea = new JTextArea();
        add(_jTextArea);
        add(_jButtonStartGameServer, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        _initialized = true;
    }

    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("init... " + Thread.currentThread());
        try
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    initComponents();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("start... " + Thread.currentThread());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                setSize(640/2, 480/2);
            }
        });
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        System.out.println("stop... " + Thread.currentThread());
        shutdownGameServer();
    }

    public void destroy()
    {
        System.out.println("destroy " + Thread.currentThread());
        shutdownGameServer();
    }

    void displayException(Throwable t)
    {
        log("Got exception: " + t);
    }


    void processMessageFromOtherPlayer(String msg)
    {
        log("Received message from other player: " + msg);
    }

    void gameServerThreadExiting()
    {
        shutdownGameServer();
    }

    public void startupGameServer()
    {
        _gameServer = new GameServer();
        _gameServerThread = new Thread(_gameServer);
        _gameServerThread.start();
        _isStarted = true;
        _jButtonStartGameServer.setText("Stop Game Server");
    }

    public void shutdownGameServer()
    {
        GameServer gs = _gameServer;
        if (gs != null)
        {
            gs.cancel();
        }
        Thread t = _gameServerThread;
        try
        {
            if (t != null)
            {
                t.join();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        _gameServer = null;
        _jButtonStartGameServer.setText("Start Game Server");
        _isStarted = false;
    }

    void log(final String msg)
    {
        System.out.println("Log (" + Thread.currentThread() + "): " + msg);
        Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(_jTextArea.getText());
                sb.append(msg);
                sb.append("\n");
                _jTextArea.setText(sb.toString());
            }
        };
        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread())
        {
            r.run();
        }
        else
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
        }
    }

    class GameServer implements Runnable
    {
        volatile ServerSocket _ss = null;
        volatile Socket _s = null;
        volatile InputStream _sis = null;
        volatile boolean _cancel = false;

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                _ss = new ServerSocket(9999);
                log("Waiting for other player, listening on port: " + _ss.getLocalPort());
                _s = _ss.accept();
                log("Connection accepted from: " + _s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                _sis = _s.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_sis, "UTF-8"));
                while (true)
                {
                    if (_cancel)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    final String msg = br.readLine();
                    if (msg == null)
                    {
                        // connection closed / lost
                        break;
                    }
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            processMessageFromOtherPlayer(msg);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (final Throwable t)
            {
                // don't show the user the exception if the user is canceling
                if (!_cancel)
                {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            displayException(t);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    // even if the user is canceling, we might be interested in the exception, though
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            log("Game server thread exiting...");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    gameServerThreadExiting();
                }

            });
        }

        public void cancel()
        {
            _cancel = true;

            ServerSocket ss = _ss;
            if (ss != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ss.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Socket s = _s;
            if (s != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    s.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            InputStream sis = _sis;
            if (sis != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    sis.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code should solve the freeze-problem, but the other Problem would be, that I still have to wait until the Server is connected, until I can continue with the other calculations. How should I do this? 
And the other thing is that I have to return a value.

Comment: The server is connected after the line of code `log("Connection accepted from: " + _s.getRemoteSocketAddress());`, so you could place more code there.  I don't know what you mean specifically by: return a value.  This is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: I want the program to continue where it was before. like:  
...  
if (mode==SERVER){  
info = //start the Server and send info2/receive info   
else if (mode==CLIENT){  
info2 = //Connect to Server and send info/receive info2  
}  
infototal=info+info2  
... 

"I don't know what you mean specifically by: return a value. This is somewhat ambiguous."
The Server-side and Client-side both send and receive some data that is nesessary for the following calculations so I have to return the informations.